# stringTOint conversion with octal and hexal

Tags: c, arrays, string, hex, octal

I have implemented a method that converts a given array of characters into a decimal integer. The method takes every character out of the array, calculates its decimal value and multiplys it with 10^n, where n gets incremeted with every iteration.

> So for example the array 4711 would be converted like this.
>   1*10^0 + 1*10^1 + 7*10^2 + 4*10^3 = 4711 as decimal value.

My question now is how to extend the functionality so the stringTOint method is also able to handle octal and hexal values, e.g. 023 or 0x1A.

```
/** Converts the given array of characters into a decimal integer */
int stringTOint(char str[]) {
int i, flag, offset, n,base;
flag = 0;
base = 10;
char c = '0';
/*if the first char in the array is '-', the minus flag gets set */
if (str[0] == '-') {
    flag = -1;
}
if (flag == -1) {
    offset = 1;
} else {
    offset = 0;
}
if(offset == 0) {
    if (str[0] == '0' && (str[1] != 'x' && str[1] != 'X') ) {
        base = 8;  // Octal
    } else if (str[0] == '0' && (str[1] == 'x' || str[1] == 'X')) {
        base = 16; // Hexadecimal
        offset = offset + 2;
    }
}else if(offset == 1) {
    if (str[1] == '0' && (str[2] != 'x' && str[2] != 'X') ) {
        base = 8;  // Octal
    } else if (str[1] == '0' && (str[2] == 'x' || str[2] == 'X')) {
        base = 16; // Hexadecimal
        offset = offset + 2;
    }
}
n = 0;
/*Loop runs until terminating NULL gets found in array */
for (i = offset; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    n = n * base + str[i] - c;
}
/*value becomes negative if the negative flag was set */
if (flag == -1) {
    n = -n;
}
/* n gets returned */
return n;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure: you *do* know that there is a standard library function that does what you coded here as well as what you want to add?

Comment: Yes im aware of the strtol mehtod, but i dont want to use any librarys

Comment: You already know how to check for negative numbers. What makes you think that checking for the `'0'` prefix (possibly followed by `'x'` or `'X'`) would be much different?

Comment: "[I] dont want to use any librarys"... Why? Is this part of an assignment? If not, then the standard library is *standard* and `strtol` will be available everywhere.

Comment: I guess i would be able to handle those with some if statements, but im unsure how to change my calculation based on the fact that i have an octal or hexal value. Could i change my base of 10 to 8 or 16 depending on the case of octal or hexal values?

Comment: The `10` in the expression `n * 10` is for the base. Use a variable for the base. Then add special cases for `'A'` to `'F'` ([`isalpha`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/isalpha) is very useful for that) if `base == 16`. You could also add a check for `8` and `9` if `base == 8`.

Comment: Oh and note that while `str[i] - '0'` is well-defined for digits, the corresponding for characters (e.g. `str[i] - 'A'`) is *not* defined by the C standard (though it works for ASCII which is arguably the only encoding you will probably encounter anyway).

Comment: I have implemented the functionality now and its running well for decimal and octal values but hexal values are still a problem. 0xA gets converted to 72 decimal, while it should be 10. This happens because the char 'A' has the decimal value 65 in the ASCII table. Now that 65 - the '0' (which is 48 in ASCII) I get the value 17. So if I have a char in hexal i need to substratct not by '0', but by 65 to get the desired decimal value. My question now is how can I change this during the calculation, because with 0x1A i first need -'0' for the 1, and then I need -'A' for the A.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the code was updated and now doesn't contain errors

Comment: @anatolyg it surely contains errors.  A to F is not been handled for hex numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not handling the cases `A` to `F` for hexa decimal values.

```
   for (i = offset; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
       int value = (str[i] > ='A' && stri[i]<='F')? (str[i]-'A'+10):(str[i]-'0');
       n = n * base + value;
    }
```

That is if char is `A` to `F`, just subtract `A` from `char` and add `10` to get the hexa decimal representation.

Note: You need to use `%X` or `%x` to print in hexadecimal notation.

Comment: Im not sure if I get that notation. So the first part (str[i] > ='A' && stri[i]<='B')? checks the condition and based on the outcome it takes either (str[i]-'A'+10) or (str[i]-'0').

Comment: Yes. I had typo just corrected it `(str[i] > ='A' && stri[i]<='B')` --> `(str[i] > ='A' && stri[i]<='F')`

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to have an array of valid digits. Use `strchr` to check if the digit is valid. If valid, the difference between the pointers is the value to add without having to subtract character constants.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int stringTOint(char *str, int *number) {
    char *digits = "0123456789";//pointer to string literal
    char *valid = NULL;
    char add = 0;
    int sign = 1;
    int base = 10;

    *number = 0;
    while ( ' ' == *str || '\t' == *str) {
        str++;//skip leading spaces tabs
    }
    if ( '-' == *str || '+' == *str) {
        if ( '-' == *str) {
            sign = -1;
        }
        str++;
    }
    if ( '0' == *str) {
        digits = "01234567";//assign pointer to different string literal
        base = 8;
        str++;
        if ( 'x' == *str) {//lowercase
            digits = "0123456789abcdef";
            base = 16;
            str++;
        }
        if ( 'X' == *str && '0' == *(str - 1)) {//uppercase
            digits = "0123456789ABCDEF";
            base = 16;
            str++;
        }
    }
    while (*str) {//not at terminating zero
        if ( ( valid = strchr ( digits, *str))) {//is a valid digit
            add = valid - digits;//value to add is difference between pointers
            *number = *number * base + add;
            str++;
        }
        else {
            *number = 0;
            return 0;//not a valid digit
        }
    }

    *number = *number * sign;
    return 1;
}

int main ( void) {
    char text[100] = "";
    int value = 0;

    do {
        printf ( "enter an integer\n\t(leading 0 octal or leading 0x hexal)\n\tor enter done\n");
        if ( fgets ( text, sizeof text, stdin)) {
            if ( '\n' == text[0]) {
                break;//exit on empty line
            }
            text[strcspn ( text, "\n")] = 0;//remove newline
            if ( stringTOint ( text, &value)) {
                printf ( "decimal value = %d\n", value);
            }
            else {
                printf ( "\n\tinput problem [%s]\n\n", text);
            }
        }
        else {
            fprintf ( stderr, "fgets EOF\n");
            return 0;
        }
    } while ( strcmp ( text, "done"));//exit if input is done
    return 0;
}
```

Add

```
    if ( 'b' == *str) {
        digits = "01";//assign pointer to different string literal
        base = 2;
        str++;
    }
```

before

```
    while (*str) {//not at terminating zero
```

and binary value may be processeed using an input such as `b1101`

To allow for a mix of upper and lower case in hexal values, remove the entire `if` block for uppercase, include `ctype.h` and change

```
if ( 'x' == *str) {
```

to

```
if ( 'x' == *str || 'X' == *str) {
```

and change

```
if ( ( valid = strchr ( digits, *str))) {
```

to

```
if ( ( valid = strchr ( digits, tolower ( *str)))) {
```

Comment: Curiously, this will not cause an error on `0xX0`. Fortunately, OP is broad enough with that question to not have considered bad input *at all*. So a plus of such a badly stated question is that you are free to interpret such side effects any which way you want!

Comment: .. Although limiting a string to `0x` to *lowercase* hex and `0X` to *uppercase* hex is going too far! I've retracted my previous upvote for that.

Answer (score -1):

My idea was to check the current char in the array if it is a decimal(so 0-9), or if it is an letter(so A-F) and then change the -'0' to -'A' and  if it is a letter and vice versa if it is a decimal number.

```
for (i = offset; str[i] != '\0'; i++) {
    if(str[i]==/*ABCDEF*/) {
     c = 'A';
} else if( str[i]==/*0123456789*/) {
        c = '0';
    }
    n = n * base + str[i] - c;
}
```

But I am unsure how to check the current character, because it only needs to be ONE of those and there should be a better way then to do 9 if statements and combine them with logical or.

Comment: Checkout my below answer it tells you how to handle.